# router.param not triggering passport.js initialize in app.use

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I've got a fairly straight forward Node Express routing app set up, to which I've just added passport.js authentication. I'm now trying to integrate this with the existing routes.

I run the basic middleware of:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

and then if I run a simple

```
app.get('/route', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.user)
});
```

I get the expected result of it printing the logged in user. So far so good...

However, I'm now trying to access this req.user within some of the child routes that I have set up. In the first route I'm trying the first step is to bring in a parameter and compare it against the req.user:

```
app.use('/route/:userId', idRouter);
```

And then:

```
idRouter.param("userId", async (req, res, next, userId) => {
  console.log(userId)
  console.log(req.user.id)
})
```

This route fires and prints out the parameter, but req.user is **undefined**. I can't see a reason why this is the case.

To help debug this I've put some logging in the deserialize function and I can see that it's not being called when I hit the idRouter. I can't see why this would be the case given it's inside an app.use function which should be called every time.

Help please!

Comment: Show declaration of `idRouter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the end, it was an issue with CORS. Just needed to include credentials in API calls.